# runAs() not working as expected

Tags: apex, unit-test, runas, system.runas

When I run the following piece of code:

```
@isTest
private static void testKybc() {

    String methodName = 'testKybc';
    ObjectUtil.debugLogBegin('TMPTriggerHandler_Test', methodName, '');

    Map<String, HttpCalloutMockFactory> endpoint2TestResp = new Map<String, HttpCalloutMockFactory> ();
    HttpCalloutMockFactory mock = new HttpCalloutMockFactory(200, 'OK', '', new Map<String, String> ());

    String endpointEquens = 'callout:Mulesoft_SPRING_X' + TMPTriggerHandler.API_PROVISIONING_EQUENS;
    String endpointKYBC = Label.ENDPOINT_KYBC;

    endpoint2TestResp.put(endpointEquens, mock);
    endpoint2TestResp.put(endpointKYBC, mock);

    HttpCalloutMock multiCalloutMock = new MultiRequestMock(endpoint2TestResp);

    
    User users = Factory.createUserTest('Administrateur');
    users.BypassTriggers__c = 'CaseBeforeUpdate;CaseAfterInsert;CaseAfterUpdate;MagasinBeforeInsert;MagasinBeforeUpdate;MagasinAfterInsert;MagasinAfterUpdate';

    update users;

    System.runAs(users) {
        Boolean exceptionThrown = false;

        System.debug('Current User: ' + UserInfo.getUserName());
        System.debug('Current Profile: ' + UserInfo.getProfileId());
```

The current user is me and not the fake user `users` that I just inserted. The Salesforce doc is clearly saying the current user in this scenario should be the 'fake' user.
Does anyone know why `runAs(users)` is not working correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Fred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually find what was the issue.
I have a trigger on the User object:

```
public class UserTriggerHandler {

public static final String PERMISSION_NAMED_CRED_ACCESS = Label.ID_PERMISSION_NAMEDCREDENTIAL;
public static final String CLASSNAME = 'UserTriggerHandler';

public void afterInsert(List<User> newTmps) {
    
    if (UtilsBypass.canTrigger('UserAfterInsert')) {
        
        String methodName = 'afterInsert';
        Set<Id> setUserIds = new Set<Id> ();
        Set<PermissionSetAssignment> setPermissionSetAssignment = new Set<PermissionSetAssignment> ();

        for (User u : newTmps) {
            setUserIds.add(u.Id);
        }

        if (!setUserIds.isEmpty()) {

            List<User> listUsers = [Select id, Profile.UserLicense.Name from User where Id in :setUserIds and Profile.UserLicense.Name like '%Community%'];
            ObjectUtil.debugLog(CLASSNAME, methodName, ' listUsers = ' + listUsers);

            if (!listUsers.isEmpty() && listUsers != null) {
                for (User u : listUsers) {
                    ObjectUtil.debugLog(CLASSNAME, methodName, ' u = ' + u);
                    PermissionSetAssignment pa = new PermissionSetAssignment();
                    pa.AssigneeId = u.Id;
                    pa.PermissionSetId = PERMISSION_NAMED_CRED_ACCESS;

                    setPermissionSetAssignment.add(pa);

                    ObjectUtil.debugLog(CLASSNAME, methodName, ' setPermissionSetAssignment = ' + setPermissionSetAssignment);
                }

                if (!setPermissionSetAssignment.isEmpty()) {
                    insert new List<PermissionSetAssignment> (setPermissionSetAssignment);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Is this piece of code i use the method canTrigger() from the class UtilsBypass:

```
public with sharing class UtilsBypass {

private static Set<String> bypassedTriggers; /** Set of triggers to be bypassed*/
private static User currentUser; /** Current User **/

/**
 * Static getter returning the current user.
 * Current User is queried in the Database if not loaded yet in Cache.
 *
 * @return User The context User
 */
public static User getCurrentUser() {

    if(currentUser == null) {
        currentUser = [SELECT ID, BypassTriggers__c, UserName,Profile.Name, Profile.Id, Email
                        FROM User WHERE ID =:UserInfo.getUserID() LIMIT 1];
    }

    return currentUser;
}

/**
* Static method returning true when an apex trigger can execute, false if
* it must be bypassed
*
* @param aTriggerName Name of the Apex Trigger written the same way it has been entered in the
*                  BypassTriggers__c field of the user
* @return Boolean true if the trigger can execute, false else
*/
public static Boolean canTrigger(String aTriggerName) {

    Boolean canTrigger = true;

    if(getBypassedTriggers().contains(aTriggerName)) {
        canTrigger = false;
    }


    return canTrigger;
}

/**
* Static method returning the set of apex triggers to bypass
*
* @return Set<String> The set of triggers to be bypassed
*/
private static Set<String> getBypassedTriggers()  {

    if(bypassedTriggers == null) {

        bypassedTriggers = new Set<String>();

        String bypassedTriggerString = getCurrentUser().BypassTriggers__c;

        if(bypassedTriggerString != null) {
            bypassedTriggers.addAll(bypassedTriggerString.split(';'));
        }
    }

    return bypassedTriggers;
}


/**
* Test Method to reset static variables
*/
public static void reset() {

    bypassedTriggers = null;
    currentUser = null;
}
```

}

Since i insert in the test class a fake user

```
User users = Factory.createUserTest('Administrateur');
```

the trigger is fired followed by the canTrigger() which makes a query to get my user...